# Python Iterative Imputation

Tags: python, loops, dataframe, missing-data, imputation

> I have a dataset with missing values that I want to impute, using the StdDev/Mean of the existing data *within each feature, for each country, over time*.

I want to set up a **loop/iteration** that goes over the groups using `groupby` and lambda or forloop, and impute the missing values iteratively.

#### Current DF:

(There are far more than 3 years, 3 countries, and 3 features)

```
[country, feature, year, value]

USA  A  1995  8
USA  B  1995  NaN
USA  C  1995  326
USA  A  1996  14
USA  B  1996  42
USA  C  1996  NaN
USA  A  1997  NaN
USA  B  1997  50
USA  C  1997  400

CHN  A  1995  6
CHN  B  1995  34
CHN  C  1995  NaN

CHN  A  1996  NaN
CHN  B  1996  NaN
CHN  C  1996  381

CHN  A  1997  23
CHN  B  1997  54
CHN  C  1997  412
```

```
grp = df.groupby(['country', 'series'])
 
for country, group in grp: 

    return ????Some Iteration????
```

> Expected output would return the df with the NaN values now imputed as the StdDev values ***for each country, with respect to each feature.***
>
> > **Not** the StdDev of the **all** the features/all the countries combined as a whole.

Thanks for any and all input.

Comment: Please share the data in a format that is easy to use. Can you explain the algorithm for replacing the NaNs in greater detail? What have you tried?

Comment: You can use scikit-learn's [Iterative Imputer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.IterativeImputer.html) to impute missing values iteratively using all other features. Note that this estimator is still experimental.

Comment: **Started a new question with screen cap** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59254737/python-impyute-or-iterativeimpute